# How to compute column sum on the basis of other column value in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

| P | T1 | T2 | T3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 2 |

In the above pandas dataframe df,
I want to add columns on the basis of the value of column 'P'.

```
if df['P'] == 0: 0
if df['P'] == 1: T1 (=1)
if df['P'] == 2: T1+T2 (=3+1=4)
if df['P'] == 3: T1+T2+T3 (=1+0+2=3)
```

In other words, I want to add from T1 to TN if df['P'] == N.
How can I implement this with Python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

For sum values by `P` column create mask by broadcasting `np.arange` by length of filtered columns by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), compare by `P` values and this mask pass to [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), last use `sum` per rows:

```
np.random.seed(20)
    
c = [f'{x}{i + 1}' for x in ['T','U','V'] for i in range(3)]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(4, size=(10,10)), columns=['P'] + c)

arrP = df['P'].to_numpy()[:, None]

for c in ['T','U','V']:
    df1 = df.filter(regex=rf'^{c}')
    df[f'{c}_SUM'] = df1.where(np.arange(len(df1.columns)) < arrP, 0).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   P  T1  T2  T3  U1  U2  U3  V1  V2  V3  T_SUM  U_SUM  V_SUM
0  3   2   3   3   0   2   1   0   3   2      8      3      5
1  3   2   0   2   0   1   2   2   3   3      4      3      8
2  0   1   2   2   2   0   1   1   3   1      0      0      0
3  3   2   2   2   1   3   2   1   3   2      6      6      6
4  3   1   1   3   1   2   2   0   2   3      5      5      5
5  2   3   2   3   1   1   1   0   3   0      5      2      3
6  2   3   2   3   3   3   2   1   1   2      5      6      2
7  3   2   0   2   1   1   2   2   2   3      4      4      7
8  2   2   1   0   2   2   0   3   3   0      3      4      6
9  2   2   3   2   2   3   2   2   1   1      5      5      3
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick solution. Actually, The dataframe has many columns. ...P....T1,T2,T3,..T10, U1,U2,...,U12, V1,V2,...,V8. I want to make columns T_SUM, U_SUM, V_SUM which contains each column sum on the basis of the value of P (as in my question). Would you please update your solution?

Comment: @YimJune - answer was edited with some sample data

Comment: Thank you jezrael. I'd better consider tril and filter fuctions. But in your sample df, T_SUM( also U_SUM, V_SUM) doesn't seem to be calculated on the basis of P. (e.g. in 4th row, P=2 but T_SUM=9 (it should be 5)) And FYI, my actual dataframe P is not sorted. (P = 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 4, ... like this). So I wonder if I can use np.tril function for my actual dataframe.

Comment: @YimJune - Answer was edited.

Comment: Perfect! My problem has been solved. Thanks for your great help. :)